# Data correlation in Java API

Tags: java, api, correlation

I have big data storage. It consist of 3 columns (id of specific type of data, data value, name of region for specific data value). I have like 800 specific type of data, each of them consist of 600-1300 specific values.

I was ordered to find correlation between data. Do u know any apis in java to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Apache Common Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) Library can calculate the Pearson and the Spearman Correlation if that is what you're looking for. Take a closer look at the [Statistics](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html) part.